# What is the difference in Font display

Tags: css, blackberry, browser, fonts, styles

I am trying to mimic the Fonts used in an application. I believe I have tried all `font-*` and `text-*` CSS properties but my text (on top) appears blurred in comparison to original app's text (bottom)

Browser: Blackberry Bold Browser

[image]

What CSS should I apply to make my top text appear similar to one below?

Comment: I guess different browsers render fonts differently. For example Firefox makes them look crisp like bacon whereas Chrome makes text look slightly ragged around the edges. I think your blackberry browser makes text look blurry.

Comment: both the screenshots are from the same device and browser :(

Comment: did you check if the application is using an image instead of blurry text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the use of JQueryMobile's `data-position="fixed"` on the header was causing this blurryness. Removing this option made the font absolutely clear and ofcourse; the header to roll away.